# How to specify alternate datasource when doing raw SQL queries in Grails 2.3.x?

Tags: sql, grails, datasource

We have a reporting read only database clone set up as an alternate datasource in our Grails application named 'reporting'.  This works great when using dynamic finders or criteria as per the grails `MyDomain.reporting.findByXXXX(..etc..)`

However there are some nasty queries that have to be done in raw SQL.  Our current way of doing this (in a service) is

```
def sessionFactory; 

public static List getSomeBigNastyData(...)
{
   sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery(
   """
   Big Ugly Query
   """ 
   ).list();
}
```

But this does not go to the reporting database and there doesn't seem to be a way of specifying 'reporting' - is there a way to specify the datasource to execute raw SQL against?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use the `dataSource` as an injected bean and `groovy.sql.Sql` to run your queries. Below is a simple example of a service that will use your data source and allow you to run a query against it.

```
package com.example

import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
import groovy.sql.Sql

class ExampleSqlService {
  def dataSource_reporting // your named data source

  List<GroovyRowResult> query(String sql) {
    def db = new Sql(dataSource_reporting)
    return db.rows(sql)
  }
}
```

Using a service (like the above example) allows you to access it from basically anywhere (Controller, Service, TagLib, Domain, etc.)